# AngularJS ui-router $state.go() not triggering state when "views" property is used

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two parallel views in my AngularJS template. One is the main page view and the second is the navigation bar view. If user is logged in, I display private data in the main view as well as a link to user account in the navigation view. If user is not logged in, I display a welcome screen as well as a login link. So, that's why I'm using two parallel views.

When using `ui-router` with one `ui-view` directive in the template, things work as expected. When using two named `ui-view` directives in my template, `$state.go('nameOfState')` doesn't work anymore.

Here's a [***Plunk***](http://plnkr.co/edit/Opia4PSZ0xHkCJbWpZau?p=preview) that's failing in triggering state with `$state.go()` because it has two views. Here's a [***Plunk***](http://plnkr.co/edit/cHz31CW0b0GfSxn6z8ph?p=preview) that shows how the same code works when there's only one view.

Why is `$state.go()` not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the controller for your home state is not being instantiated, meaning the `$state.go` call is never happening. The controllers are instantiated only on demand. Specifically, the documentation [states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers):

> Warning: The controller will not be instantiated if template is not defined.

In order to get `mainCtrl` to be instantiated, you can add a template to the `home` state and add an unnamed ui-view to index.html, or you can add a template for one or more of the existing named views (e.g. "main") for the `home` state and move the `mainCtrl` to be the controller for those views. E.g. if you replace your existing home state with the following, it should work as expected:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    views: { 
      'main': {
        template: 'main template',
        controller: mainCtrl
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @kong. It makes some sense, but why does the controller work fine in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Opia4PSZ0xHkCJbWpZau?p=preview)? I looks to me that the controller instantiation of this working Plunk is exactly the same as the other non-working Plunk.

Comment: In the working Plunk, the `<div ui-view>` is unnamed, so it matches the unnamed view for the home state and causes the controller to be instantiated. This is a little contradictory to the docs, which indicate the template is also required, but that does seem to be what's happening. Similarly, if you add and unnamed `<div ui-view></div>` to the index.html of your non-working Plunk, it should start working, since that `ui-view` will match the home state and cause the controller to instantiate and the `$state.go` call to happen.